# How to capture and work with voice in java and C#?

Tags: c#, java

I'm planning to work on a project where there will be a feature like voice capturing and sending it through a socket and playback it on the other side. Now I need to know whether there is any API in Java or C# regarding working with raw formats of voice data.

Comment: NAudio may help you: http://naudio.codeplex.com/. "NAudio is an open source .NET audio and MIDI library, containing dozens of useful audio related classes intended to speed development of audio related utilities in .NET." Look at the `WaveIn` class (not sure if it changed, but should be `WaveIn`).

Answer (score 0):

For C#, you can use NAudio library for sound capturing and playback. For JAVA, You can use `javax.sound.sampled` Package for audio capturing and playback. If you want to encode it, use 3rd party library like [jspeex](http://jspeex.sourceforge.net/) to encode and decode. Use inbuilt network libraries to send them.

**UPDATE:**

For C# try [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). Which is a managed version of DirectX and do have all the features you required (Don't know whether it is suitable for your project).